# continuous functions are measurable proof

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then f is measurable.
The definition is $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is measurable for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$

I want to prove that continuous functions are measurable. Do I need to know some other lemmas to prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of measurability? Depending on your exact definition, the proof is either very simple or you will need a (not too complicated) Lemma.

Comment: @PhoemueX I just edited the definition.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is open for all $a$. Since open sets are measurable, the proof is completed.

Comment: Can we use this argument even if our functions is from extended real-numbers to extended real numbers?

Comment: Yes, the argument is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have two unspecified assumptions in your question: the topology and the $\sigma$-algebra on $I$.

If the topology is a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra, as in $I=[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$ with the standard topology and the Borel-algebra or its completion, then the answer is trivial as in the other answer by Crostul.